# How to do a rolling sum in Excel or R, without using a for loop

Tags: r, excel, sum

I have a column of 1000 random numbers for which I would like to calculate a rolling sum with a window length of 10, in Excel or R. For the first 10 observations, the rolling sum should still be calculated with a partial window length. I don't find a rolling sum feature in Excel or R though.

My current attempt in R is using a loop. It works correctly, however, loops are inefficient. See my attempt below.

```
 vector = as.vector(matrix(1,1000,nrow = 1))
for (i in 1:1000) {
  if (i<11) {
    rolling.sum[i]=sum(vector[1:i])
  } else {
    rolling.sum[i] = sum(vector[(i-10):i])
  }
}
```

- "vector" is the vector of random numbers for which a rolling sum needs to be calculated.
- "rolling.window" is the variable into which I will store the rolling sum

Comment: Look at `zoo` package for R. `zoo::rollsum(your_vector, 10)`

Comment: thanks @Sotos I tried rollapply and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this in R, which is using the rollapply function from the zoo package. Using rollapply(), one inputs the vector of values as the first argument, the window length as the second argument, and then indicates that it should be a rolling sum. The last argument indicates that it also calculates partial sums when the window length is not long enough. Note that the width argument must specify whether the window is forward looking or backwards looking. Example below:

```
vector = as.vector(matrix(1,1000,nrow = 1))
rolling.sum<<-rollapply(vector, width = list(-1:-10), sum, partial=T)
```

Comment: The code in the answer may be what you want but just in case note that it sums the 10 values *prior* to and not including the current value.  If the input is of length n the result will be of length n-1 (unless the argument `fill = NA`, say, is added.  IIf you intended to sum the 10 values up to and *including* the current value then replace the `width` argument with `width=10`.and use `rollapplyr` (or align = `"right"`)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, thank you @G.Grothendieck ! I hadn't noticed that it didn't include the ten values prior

Answer (score 0):

Taking liberties with *in another cell* for the sake of keeping to the spirit of your Title, put `1` (or a different starting value of your choice) in a cell and HOME > Editing - Fill, Series..., select Columns for Series in, Linear for Type, enter `1` for Step value: and ("in the cell next to") Stop value: whatever  limit/precedent value you want, OK.

Comment: Thank you @pnuts this did help me. However, I am seeking a neater way of doing this in a function